# Button not working in first row of table (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, html-table

Fairly new to HTML/CSS and can't seem to get the button in the first row of my table to work, all the others are working and link to my other HTML file just fine. Here is my html file:

```html
<div id="banner">
  <div class="content">
    <h1> Products </h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Price (NZD)</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>xxx</td>
        <td>xxx</td>
        <td>$xxx</td>
        <td>xxx</td>
        <td><a href="cart.html">Buy</a> // This button doesn't work!
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>xxx</td>
        <td>xxx</td>
        <td>$xxx</td>
        <td>xxx</td>
        <td><a href="cart.html">Buy</a>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>xxx</td>
        <td>xxx</td>
        <td>$xxx</td>
        <td>xxx</td>
        <td><a href="cart.html">Buy</a>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>xxx</td>
        <td>xxx</td>
        <td>$xxx</td>
        <td>xxx</td>
        <td><a href="cart.html">Buy</a>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>xxx</td>
        <td>xxx</td>
        <td>$xxx</td>
        <td>xxx</td>
        <td><a href="cart.html">Buy</a>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>xxx</td>
        <td>xxx</td>
        <td>$xxx</td>
        <td>xxx</td>
        <td><a href="cart.html">Buy</a>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Not sure what is going on, is it something to do with how I am structuring the table and if so is there a better way to go about it?

Comment: I believe there should be an enclosing </td> for each of those a links.

Comment: Absolutely look at my answer

Comment: @Dream_Cap The closing `</td>` is not required in this case and is not the issue: https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/tabular-data.html#the-td-element I cannot replicate the problem.

Comment: Where is "cart.html" located? It could be a path issue where it's in a folder like "folder/cart.html"

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing of the `td`, here is the fixed version of your code

```
<tr>
  <td>xxx</td>
  <td>xxx</td>
  <td>$xxx</td>
  <td>xxx</td>
  <td><a href="cart.html">Buy</a></td> // Add the TD here
</tr>
```

Comment: His markup is valid. You don't need a closing `</td>` if there is no more content of the parent, which is true in this case. His markup works as is: https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/tabular-data.html#the-td-element

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your link `href="cart.html"` is broken or doesn't exist.
I've tested your code with Chrome, Firefox, M Edge and the buttons work.
Also, you should close the `td` tag like suggested above (you don't *really have to if you use latest version of the web browsers I mentioned, but you should)